# Jackson: get an arbitrary node's value in a custom deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

Good time!

Say, there is a json string: `{id:'a', type:'b', category:'c'}`, and the business-logic is such that to build a category object I need to know the category name ('c') and the type ('b'). Obviously I need to write a custom deserializer (`@JsonDeserialize(using = CategoryCustomDeserializer.class)`), for the category and it is simple to get the category's name, but I can't figure out how to get the type's value... I've tried this: `jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser)`, but it returns `null`.

Please, suggest the right way to do it.

**EDIT**:
Here is the deserializer:

```
  public class CategoryNameDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Category> {

     @Override
     public Category deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if (jp.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
           String categoryName = jp.getText();
           String type = ?????? <------------------------ How to do it
           return Service.getInstance().getCategory(categoryName, type);
        }

        return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not at all clear that you need to write a custom deserializer. Indeed it would be much simpler to use Jackson POJO binding and just ignore the extra, unwanted field. If you decide, for whatever reason, to continue with the custom deserializer, then you should be able to get the type value just the same way you are getting the category name. You may want to include, in the question, your current deserializer code.

Comment: @Perception, actually I really need the custom deserializer, cause there are some things to do while building the Category object. I've added the deserializer code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found an answer. This is a workaround, but it works. One can reset the parser with such a method:

```
private JsonParser getResetParser(JsonParser jp) throws IOException {
    JsonFactory factory = jp.getCodec().getFactory();

    StringReader inputSource = (StringReader) jp.getInputSource();
    inputSource.reset();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputSource);
    String source = br.readLine();

    return factory.createJsonParser(source);
}
```

and then:

```
private String findTokenText(JsonParser jp, String fieldName) throws IOException {
    JsonParser parser = getResetParser(jp);
    while (true) {
        parser.nextToken();
        if (parser.hasCurrentToken()) {
            switch (parser.getCurrentToken()) {
                case END_ARRAY:
                case END_OBJECT:
                case NOT_AVAILABLE:
                case START_ARRAY:
                case START_OBJECT:
                case VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT:
                case VALUE_FALSE:
                case VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT:
                case VALUE_NUMBER_INT:
                case VALUE_TRUE:
                    // do nothing
                    break;
                case FIELD_NAME:
                    String currentName = parser.getCurrentName();
                    if (fieldName.equals(currentName)) {
                        parser.nextToken();
                        return parser.getText();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The thing I don't understand is why despite performing `inputSource.reset();` the code `jp.getText()` inside the `findTokenText` method (just tried it in a debug mode) returns "C", as if the reader was not reseted. 
Can anybody explain, why does this happen?

Another variant is to avoid customizing and use a suggestion from [this](http://djna.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/json-strings-no-rest-using-the-jackson-parser/) post.